# Converting SVG to another format fail due to delegate not being found

Tags: php, svg, debian, imagemagick

I have PHP code running on Debian stretch with ImageMagick. It tries to convert SVG to another format. Here is how it starts

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
```

The variable `$svg` contains valid SVG code in a string. If I copy this string to a text file with a `.svg` extension then it opens just fine. But `readImageBlob` throws an exception saying `no delegate for this image format`.

I have seen similar questions solved by installing more packages to the system. But I've already installed `libxml2-dev`, `librsvg2-bin`, `libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra` and `libfreetype6-dev`.

I have no idea what else I am missing.

Comment: What's the first line of the SVG file? There may be some comments, whitespace, and/or XML headers that `Imagick::readImageBlob` doesn't understand.

Comment: Also try setting a "dummy" filename to the method. `$im->readImageBlob($svg, 'filename.svg');`

Comment: Imagick::readImageBlob — Reads image from a `binary string`. You are sending ascii data, not binary. So save the string to a text file and use readImage().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get from running the following command from PHP exec()

`convert -list format`

The line SVG should say RSVG or MSVG/XML. Does it show that? if you need RSVG, you will have to install that delegate and then reinstall Imagemagick so that Imagemagick can find it. Imagemagick is used by Imagick. They are not the same. The RSVG delegate can be found by a Google Search or from linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/librsvg.html. Your svg file seems to render properly for me in Imagemagick using RSVG, but I am not sure what it should look like. It is just a graph set of horizontal lines.

I do not know much about using readImageBlob(). Just use readImage(), where you supply the path to a saved svg image file. That should work. Try that and see what you get.

Here is what I get using RSVG 2.42.2 in Imagemagick 6.9.10.3 Q16 Mac OSX were I have saved your text in a file called test.svg.

```
convert test.svg test.png
```

[image]

If I force the use of the Imagemagick MSVG/XML, it does not look as good.

```
convert MSVG:test.svg test2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed it seems it uses MSVG rather than RSVG. RSVG does it correctly. You can see here three columns but they are all zero so they show as tiny lines. MSVG which was used for me places word "Gigabytes" at a wrong position. Imagemagick was installed from a debian package. librsvg2-bin was also installed as another package afterwards. But it still uses MSVG

Comment: Imagemagick has to know or be recompiled to find RSVG. As your host if they can install Inkscape, if your Imagemagick version is  6.7.9-0 or was patched after 2012-08-14. Imagemagick will then find Inkscape and use that in place of RSVG or MSVG

Answer (score 2):

I had to prepend the `$svg` with `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` and it worked. It least it does read in the SVG and attempts to create png/jpeg. One piece of text gets misplaced during convertion though. So the task in general is still failed. But this is another issue. I think the question is answered.

Comment: Render quality depends upon which SVG renderer Imagemagick is using. You can see that with `convert -list format`. Imagemagick can use Inkscape, RSVG delegate or its own internal MSVG/XML renderer in order of best to worst quality. You would be best to install Inkscape and Imagemagick will use it if it finds it. Next, install the RSVG delegate to imagemagick and recompile Imagemagick if needed. If you post your SVG file, I can test it with my Imagemagick using RSVG.

Comment: @fmw42 I could not find such information about SVG delegates. Where can I get more details on this? I cirtainly didn't have Inkscape installed. Here is my image https://pastebin.com/fRSeHR7N It's actually a plot generated by Google Charts